# eZ Publish 5: XSLTProcessor importStyleSheet

Tags: ezpublish

I have a problem with my eZ Publish project after moving form a virtual machine to my localhost.

I get this in my error log:

```
/Publish/Core/FieldType/XmlText/Converter/Html5.php line 140
```

I think it's environment related as I had no such thing on my VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problems...Seems that there was a blank(space) in the path to my project and when importing the xls file it didn't know to escape it so was ending execution without an error message even remotely connected to the problem. SO just make sure the path to your project doesn't contain any spaces; you will probably need to configure your virtual hosts also if using any. Hope it helps